# Why won't gvim start after reinstall?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, startup

I have just reinstalled gvim 7.4 on my 64 bit Windows 7 system. `gvim.exe` now does not start, (or appears not to start - it may be exiting immediately)

If I start `vim.exe` then it works fine. This is about the GUI version not starting.

What might be the problem, and what strategies might I adopt to get further insights into what's wrong?

I can run it with a --version attribute, and I get the following:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 14:38:33)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Compiled by mool@tororo
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic             +ex_extra           +mouseshape         +syntax
+autocmd            +extra_search       +multi_byte_ime/dyn +tag_binary
+balloon_eval       +farsi              +multi_lang         +tag_old_static
+browse             +file_in_path       -mzscheme           -tag_any_white
++builtin_terms     +find_in_path       +netbeans_intg      +tcl/dyn
+byte_offset        +float              +ole                -tgetent
+cindent            +folding            +path_extra         -termresponse
+clientserver       -footer             +perl/dyn           +textobjects
+clipboard          +gettext/dyn        +persistent_undo    +title
+cmdline_compl      -hangul_input       -postscript         +toolbar
+cmdline_hist       +iconv/dyn          +printer            +user_commands
+cmdline_info       +insert_expand      -profile            +vertsplit
+comments           +jumplist           +python/dyn         +virtualedit
+conceal            +keymap             +python3/dyn        +visual
+cryptv             +langmap            +quickfix           +visualextra
+cscope             +libcall            +reltime            +viminfo
+cursorbind         +linebreak          +rightleft          +vreplace
+cursorshape        +lispindent         +ruby/dyn           +wildignore
+dialog_con_gui     +listcmds           +scrollbind         +wildmenu
+diff               +localmap           +signs              +windows
+digraphs           -lua                +smartindent        +writebackup
-dnd                +menu               -sniff              -xfontset
-ebcdic             +mksession          +startuptime        -xim
+emacs_tags         +modify_fname       +statusline         -xterm_save
+eval               +mouse              -sun_workshop       +xpm_w32
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE 
-DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x040
0  /Fo.\ObjGOLYHTRi386/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME 
-DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL 
-DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl85.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.5\" 
-DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" 
-DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python32.dll\" 
-DFEAT_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl514.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY 
-DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=19 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby192.dll\" 
-DFEAT_BIG /Fd.\ObjGOLYHTRi386/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib 
advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib 
version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib libcmt.lib 
oleaut32.lib  user32.lib      /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python32.lib   
"E:\tcl\lib\tclstub85.lib" WSock32.lib xpm\x86\lib\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `gvim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file for suspect commands.

Also, it may be something in your configuration, so try launching with `gvim -N -u NONE` (which ignores plugins and your `.vimrc`).

Comment: The logging didn't help much, but after starting it without plugins and then editing the vimrc (it created a new one - so I guess it was missing) the next time it started up fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your Python version. GVim seems to be built against Python `2.7.9`, and the latest 2.x version is `2.7.11`. Run `python --version` to see which version you have. Also make sure that both your gvim and python installation are x86 or 64.

With Python `2.7.11` *and* some plugins, it'll crash silently. You can also try adding `finish` to your vimrc (or rename it) to launch vim without plugins, it should start correctly (but as soon as you re-enable your plugins, it will fail again)

If you used *chocolatey* to install Python on Windows, it may auto-upgrade - use `pin` to prevent upgrading (`choco pin add --name python2-x86_32 --version 2.7.9`)